# How to call method in slide toggle angular 2 (material - tool bar)?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

```
HTML FILE
```

```html
                            <div class=" -toolbar ">
                                <p>
                                    <mat-toolbar>
                                        <h4>Offer Mapping</h4>
                                        <div class="row align-right col-md-offset-7 col-md-1 ">
                                            <mat-form-field class="button-spacing">
                                                <mat-select placeholder="select">

                                                </mat-select>
                                            </mat-form-field>
                                            <button mat-raised-button (click)="campaignPrioritise()"  [disabled] class="button-spacing">
                                                Prioritise
                                            </button>
                                            
                                           <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="createNewCampaign()">
                                                <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
                                            </button>
                                            <mat-slide-toggle *ngIf= "let element" class="material-icons color_green" matTooltip="Prioritise"
                                            [checked]="element.priority" (change)="campaignPrioritise(element)"></mat-slide-toggle>
                                        </div>
                                    </mat-toolbar>
                                </p>
                            </div>
```

TS File

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';



/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  timeSelection1 = '';
  timeSelection2 = '';

  selected: any[] = [];
  selected1 : any[] = [];



on(element){
  let priority = false;
        element.priority = !element.priority;
}

}
```

when i slide the toggle the priority variable becomes true and false 
how do i achieve this is mat tool bar I was trying to write some code but slide toggle is not showing in to the mat tool bar!
when i press the toggle switch the priority switch becomes true and when slide to left toggle switch becomes false.
Here it is my StackBlitz Link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/toggle12345677709-gfj1?file=main.ts

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It is not clear from your question and the stackblitz doesn't work properly.

Comment: @FabianKüng how to add mat toggle in toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `element` declared in the above code.If you have the `element` it works properly

```
element:any = {
   priority: false
 }

on(){
  let priority = false;
  this.element.priority = !this.element.priority;
}
```